# Alteryx & tableau - OCILogon2 Error: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, tableau-api, database-administration, alteryx

I have two database servers Test and Prod. I installed all the oracle client tools required for establishing connections. I am able to connect to both of Test & PROD using basic connection type from SQL developer. Also I am able to connect to the Test environment using Tableau & Alteryx but when I try to connect to PROD it throws TNS listener error(both Alteryx and Tableau). I am using Oracle OCI to connect in Alteryx and basic connection type in tableau. I did not set up any TNS names from the beginning

Oracle server version: 12C
SQL Developer: 18.4.0.376.1900
Tableau: 2019.3.4
Alteryx: 2018.4.5

Comment: please amend your question to include the jdbc connection strings/urls for both SQL Developer and say Tableau for the production system - being careful to obscure info like actual usernames, passwords, ip addresses, etc

Comment: Identified the problem, I am using SID that I am using in Oracle SQL developer for Tableau and Alteryx as well. But, I should use different one from what I am using for oracle SQL developer
Ex: Oracle SQl developer SID - a55g44f
Tableau and Alteryx SID - a55g44f.abcd.com